# Security of Submitting Form Data via iFrame?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, forms, security, salesforce

Ok so let me give a slight background as to my situation here:

- Redesigning a website in WordPress
- Website has a few forms that submit to Salesforce
- The powers-that-be don't believe the security is up-to-par for PHP form data (it's a windows shop, slowly branching out to other technologies)
- They want to create the forms in ASP

So here's my question.  How secure would that form data be if I was submitting it via iframe? My initial thoughts are to grab the form via iframe and kill off all of the scrollbars, etc. to make it look as seamless as possible.

It's an issue that I have had to deal with but I am just trying to figure out the best solution here.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Ahh, bobble-head bosses. Yep yep yep. What is any more insecure about a page in an  `iframe` sending data from a browser compared to not being in an `iframe`? It's the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question; [Iframe Security Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163985/iframe-security-issues) should be able to help regarding iframe security, but you will struggle to access and manipulate DOM elements due to Cross Domain Scripting restrictions..

If the form security is a potential issue (although i would be interested to know why..) then maybe look at the salesforce api as you can handle the form data in the way you see fit and then use SOAP or REST clients to handle the business logic...

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm for SOAP
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm for REST

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks.  I feel like i'm fighting a pointless fight but I don't see the reason this 1 website should ever need 2 separate environments to live.